# Scripts failing in Safari browser

Tags: robotframework

Most of our scripts are failing in safari browser. Values are entering in Input box. Its working all other browser except safari. Is anyone facing this issue?

I contacted browserstack they are saying its safari driver issue.

Comment: _"... scripts are failing ..."_ We're going to need a lot more detail than that. Try including any error messages you see or some relevant code.

Comment: There is no error msg. It will not enter any values in the page and hit submit button